# Is there any way to parse blocks inside widget area?

Tags: widgets, block-editor, parse

As widgets are outside post content, i couldn't find the way to parse blocks inserted inside widget area for ex. `"sidebar-1"`

We use something like below for parsing post contents,

```
$post = get_post('100');
parse_blocks($post->post_content)
```

But for widgets, i couldn't do it like below,

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1');
$widget_content = ob_get_clean();
parse_blocks($widget_content)
```

Comment: how are you inserting blocks inside a widget? If you mean the entire widget area, you want the precursor that's processed by `dynamic_sidebar`, not the end result. What are you trying to do that requires this? There are filters for modifying or inspecting blocks when they're rendered

Comment: I meant inside each sidebar (widget location). for ex. i have registered sidebar named "sidebar-1" and also having heading, paragraph & image block inside that sidebar. Now i want to get the attributes of those blocks for processing some backend operation inside functions.php. Hope i explained better.

Comment: what's the backend processing you're trying to do?

Comment: For ex. If the attribute "fontSize" is above 40px, i want to change sidebar width.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar use case where I needed to parse block widgets inside available widget areas. I opened an issue on the [Gutenberg Repository](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/44616). After some links and suggestions, I was able to write this code which can parse blocks inside available widget areas:

```
// Get all available widgets in the widget areas
$widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

if ( isset( $widgets ) && is_array( $widgets ) ) {
    
    global $wp_widget_factory;
    
    $blocks_array = [];
    
    foreach( $widgets as $key => $value ) {
        
        // Skip for inactive widgets
        if ( $key == 'wp_inactive_widgets' ) {
            continue;
        }
        
        if ( isset( $value ) && is_array( $value ) && ! empty( $value ) ) {
            
            foreach( $value as $widget_id ) {
                
                $parsed_id = wp_parse_widget_id( $widget_id );
                $widget_object = $wp_widget_factory->get_widget_object( $parsed_id['id_base'] );

                if ( $widget_object && isset( $parsed_id['number'] ) ) {
                    $all_instances                   = $widget_object->get_settings();
                    $instance                        = $all_instances[ $parsed_id['number'] ];
                    $serialized_instance             = serialize( $instance );
                    $prepared['instance']['encoded'] = base64_encode( $serialized_instance );
                    $prepared['instance']['hash']    = wp_hash( $serialized_instance );

                    if ( ! empty( $widget_object->widget_options['show_instance_in_rest'] ) ) {
                        // Use new stdClass so that JSON result is {} and not [].
                        $prepared['instance']['raw'] = empty( $instance ) ? new stdClass : $instance;
                        $blocks_array[] = parse_blocks( $prepared['instance']['raw']['content'] );
                    }                                
                }
            } // inner foreach
        } // isset $value
    } //foreach
    
    // This is the complete blocks data with attributes and other settings
    print_r( $blocks_array );

} // all widgets
```